# Morphism induced by a globally generated line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of dimension $n$. Let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$. Then $L$ embeds $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^{h^0(L)-1}$. Hence $h^0(L)-1\geq \textrm{dim}\, X$. So $h^0(L)\geq n+1$. So $L$ has at least $n+1$ sections.

Suppose $L$ is an ample and globally generated line bundle, is the same true? We have a morphism $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{h^0(L)-1}$. Then do we have the inequality $h^0(L)-1\geq n$? More precisely, can an ample, globally generated line bundle induce a morphism to a projective space of smaller dimension?

What if $L$ is just a globally generated line bundle?

Comment: The induced morphism is finite if and only if $L$ is ample.

Comment: Your last question is easily answered by the structure sheaf which gives rise to a morphism to a point.

Comment: @MooS, Your first comment then means that, if $L$ is ample, then the morphism $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{h^0(L)-1}$ is finite. If $h^0(L)-1<n$, then the morphism is to a projective space of smaller dimension. And so the fibers  are not 0 dimensional. So the morphism is not finite. Thus $h^0(L)-1\geq n$. Is this correct?

Comment: @MooS, can you tell me what is the reference for that fact?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: For example Görtz/Wedhorn 13.84. In Fulton's book this is even the definition of ample.